# JOGL OpenGL GLCanvas set to a fixed resolution

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am using JOGL with a GLCanvas in a java app which is displayed fullscreen 1920x1080, is it possible to set the resolution of the GLCanvas or GL to say half this 960x540 and have the canvas/gl upscale it?

Comment: Without true resolution change You will only meet partially working solutions. Even if You manage to render all in just half the res (shouldn't be so hard, since you can define viewport or render to pbuffer) You're still left with one big canvas to fill. And in the end, the fillrate can still be much of a limitation.

Comment: Why you want to do that?